# sql query with if logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have table in which one of the column(info) contains below type of information, I want to run a query which check all the records and if it finds ""matched data"" value then remove the data.

```
Current value 
"{""value"":{""Volume ID"":""12345"",""matched data"":""eJzBFPafhF1xu0JdwH""}}"
Expected value 
"{""value"":{""Volume ID"":""12345"",""matched data"":"" ""}}"
```

Comment: What's your dbms? where is your sql?

Comment: Microsoft sql server 2014, table name is datacollection

Comment: So your colnum data is `JSON`?

Comment: yes  its json value

Comment: @D-Shih can this be possible ?

Comment: Is the Json format string above fixed?

Comment: format is fixed but the value between codes can vary .

Comment: I answered you can try it @gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Json` format string is fixed.  you can use `CHARINDEX` with `SUBSTRING` 
 and `REPLACE` method

1. get `""matched data""` string to be start index by `CHARINDEX` method
2. use `CHARINDEX` to get `}}` to get the be the end index.
3. `SUBSTRING` get contain `""matched data""` key value data.
4. `REPLACE` to your expect format.

Final use Replace to get your expected result

**TestDLL**

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   Col1 VARCHAR(1000)
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES ('"{""value"":{""Volume ID"":""12345"",""matched data"":""eJzBFPafhF1xu0JdwH""}}"');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('"{""value"":{""Volume ID"":""12345"",""matched data"":""test1213""}}"');
```

**Query**

```
SELECT REPLACE(Col1,SUBSTRING(Col1,CHARINDEX('""matched data"":', Col1) ,CHARINDEX('}}', Col1)  - CHARINDEX('""matched data"":', Col1)),'""matched data"":"" ""')
FROM T
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c897511a2b014442331af85610a03f21)

Comment: Thank you very much . I salute to you for your smart approach and quick understanding which helped me to fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

idk what exactly do you need, but if you want to find out the solution to the if statement in sql your way is to use case.

Example:

```
CASE expression
    WHEN condition1 THEN result1
    WHEN condition2 THEN result2
   ...
    WHEN conditionN THEN resultN
    ELSE result
END
```

Example on a full query:

```
SELECT CustomerName, City, Country
FROM Customers
ORDER BY
(CASE
    WHEN City IS NULL THEN Country
    ELSE City
END);
```

Comment: thanks should i try something select info from datacollection
ORDER BY (CASE  WHEN ""matched data"" 
not sure now how to jump to next statement making value as null?

Comment: @gary it's a little bit hard for me to understand what exactly did you mean. 
You are asking about the situations when value is null?

Comment: If you see my current value and expected value . I need to run a query which should look for ""matched data"" and delete all the value which is in between next ""matched data"" :"" i want to delete all data from these codes""